# In AWS Sagemaker Pipeline, handing off CreateModelStep to TransformStep results in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inference'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

In AWS Sagemaker Pipeline, I have a `CreateModelStep` that connects to a `TransformStep`. When I get to the TransformStep, I see the following error thrown.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_modules.py", line 258, in import_module
    module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inference'
```

My steps are defined as follows.

```
model_step = CreateModelStep(
    name='CreateModel',
    model=Model(
        name='RandomForestModel',
        image_uri=training_step.properties.AlgorithmSpecification.TrainingImage,
        model_data=training_step.properties.ModelArtifacts.S3ModelArtifacts,
        sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
        role=role
    ),
    inputs=CreateModelInput(
        instance_type=instance_type,
        accelerator_type='ml.eia1.medium',
    )
)


transform_step = TransformStep(
    name='Transform',
    transformer=training_estimator.transformer(
        instance_count=instance_count, 
        instance_type=instance_type,
        accept='text/csv',
        env={
            'SAGEMAKER_DEFAULT_INVOCATIONS_ACCEPT': 'text/csv', 
            'SAGEMAKER_USE_NGINX': 'False', 
            'SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM': 'inference.py',
            'SAGEMAKER_REGION': region,
            'SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY': '/opt/ml/model/'
        },
        model_name=model_step.properties.ModelName,
        output_path=f's3://{default_bucket}/RandomForestTransform'
    ),
    inputs=TransformInput(data=batch_data)
)
```

From the logs, I can see that a `pip install` was done. I think the problem comes from `SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM='inference.py'`. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [sagemaker_containers](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-containers/blob/master/src/sagemaker_containers/_modules.py#L237-L258) it is failing to import your inference.py. Confirm that you do in fact have an `inference.py` in the `model.tar.gz`/  `model_data=training_step.properties.ModelArtifacts.S3ModelArtifacts`